# Как составить JPQL-запрос для получения сущности, дочерние сущности которой могут быть null (при этом эти сущности участвуют в условии WHERE)?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa

Имеется сущность `Truck`. Она связана с сущностями `Dirty`, `Gravel` и `Sand` отношением OneToOne. Причём две из трёх этих сущностей всегда null *(как бы грузовик может в один момент иметь только один груз, остальные будут null)*.

**Truck:**

```
@Entity
public class Truck {
    
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    String owner;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "truck")
    Dirty dirty;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "truck")
    Gravel gravel;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "truck")
    Sand sand;
}
```

**Классы грузов *(наследуются от AbstractCargo)*:**

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class AbstractCargo {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "truck_id")
    Truck truck;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    int weight;
}

@Entity
public class Dirty {
}

@Entity
public class Gravel {
}

@Entity
public class Sand {
}
```

Теперь мне необходимо получить список сущностей `Truck`, свойство `owner` которых равно некоторой строке и которые связаны с сущностями `Dirty`, `Gravel` или `Sand`, в которых свойство `weight` равно некоторому числу *(напоминаю, что у одной сущности `Truck` может быть только один груз единовременно, остальные будут null)*. Кстати говоря, я использую `EntityGraph`, поэтому использование `JOIN` нежелательно *(Hibernate начинает ругаться)*.

Если говорить человеческим языком, то мне надо получить все грузовики, принадлежащие некоторому владельцу, у которых есть груз с массой равной некоторому числу.

Я долго пытался составить корректный JPQL-запрос, получилось только вот это:

```
SELECT t FROM Truck t, Dirty d, Gravel g, Sand s
    WHERE t.owner=:owner
    AND ((d.truck.id=t.id AND d.weight=:weight) OR
         (g.truck.id=t.id AND g.weight=:weight) OR
         (s.truck.id=t.id AND s.weight=:weight))
```

Но результат получается невменяемым *(строки дублируются)*.

Как мне здесь правильно составить запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL [поддерживает](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#ON_.28JPA_2.1.29) фильтрацию по ассоциации, так что вот такой запрос по идее должен работать:

```
from Truck t
  left join t.dirty d ON d.weight = :weight
  left join t.gravel g ON g.weight = :weight
  left join t.sand s ON s.weight = :weight
WHERE t.dirty IS NOT NULL
   OR t.gravel IS NOT NULL
   OR t.sand IS NOT NULL
```

Тут используется `left join`, разновидность `outer join`. Рассмотрим как работает (на примере `dirty`, для других так же).

Для основной записи (в нашем случае из таблицы `Truck`) ищется подходящая под условие запись в `Dirty`. Если нашлась - хорошо, в поле `Truck.dirty` будет записана информация об этом (в этом случае в виде прокси так как нет `fetch`), если не нашлась, то поле `dirty` будет установлено в `null`, но `truck` все равно вернется в результате запроса.

В нашем случае мы используем тот факт, что если запись в таблице, которую ми join-им не найдена, то тогда поле `dirty == null` и мы фильтруем те `Truck`-и, у которых ни одной ассоциации не удалось найти по условию на вес.

Если нужно чтобы ассоциация доставалась не лениво, то замените `left join` на `left join fetch`.

Comment: Да, это отлично работает. И совсем не конфликтует с EntityGraph. Интересно, почему? Когда я пытался в прошлы раз использовать join и EntityGraph одновременно, возникала ошибка.

Comment: EntityGraph описывает какие из ассоциаций загружать, а какие оставить ленивыми. В этом запросе join не загружает ассоциации, а только используется для фильтрации. А вообще-то нужно больше подробностей, чтобы ответить на вопрос.

Comment: Я решил создать новый вопрос по данной теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286933/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-entitygraph-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-join-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5 . Если будет желание посмотреть и ответить - милости прошу.

Comment: Немного пошёл дальше, выяснилось, что этот вариант не работает. Например, есть грузовик гружёный песком весом 100 тонн. А мы хотим найти все грузовики, в которых груз 50 тонн. Наш грузовик тоже попадёт в выборку, только Sand будет равен null (груз не загрузится из бд, тогда как сам грузовик загрузится)

Comment: Должно быть достаточно добавить условие, что хотя бы одна ассоциация должна присутствовать

Comment: Хм, разве поможет? Всё-таки Sand не null и проверку пройдёт, а вот в выборке его опять не будет. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Будет работать. Не работало потому, что тут outer join, т.е даже если нет совпадений вообще по условию, то `Truck` все равно вернется, но с пустыми ассоциациями. А теперь добавили условие, что если вообще совпадений нет, то и не возвращать такой `Truck`.

Comment: Хм. Любопытно. Для меня всё равно немного непонятно, но я проверил, это работает. Только я чуть сокращённей написал условие: `WHERE (d IS NOT NULL OR g IS NOT NULL OR s IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Если не понятно, то это значит не понимаете, как работает outer join. В этом направлении нужно смотреть.

Comment: Ну да, в SQL я далёк от профи :(

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t.somecolumn,
       COALESCE(d.somecolumn, g.somecolumn, s.somecolumn) AS somecolumn
FROM Truck t
LEFT JOIN Dirty d ON d.truck.id=t.id AND d.weight=:weight
LEFT JOIN Gravel g ON g.truck.id=t.id AND g.weight=:weight
LEFT JOIN Sand s ON s.truck.id=t.id AND s.weight=:weight
WHERE t.owner=:owner
```

Comment: Разве такой запрос не будет возвращать грузы вместо грузовиков? Не могу сейчас проверить к сожалению.

Comment: @Zhenyria Запрос возвращает поля из Truck и поля из остальных трёх таблиц, для каждого поля - первое в списке, которое не NULL,

Comment: `поля из Truck` - На выходе нужны именно грузовики (просто грузовики, которые подходят по условию). Вы не могли бы дополнить ответ, если знаете решение?

Comment: @Zhenyria Да я вообще в толк взять не могу, о чём вот Вы сейчас сказали. И чем не устраивает показанный запрос.

Comment: Я просто так понял, что вы возвращаете поля из Truck. А надо сам Truck. Или я чего-то не понял? Мне надо добраться до проекта, я тогда попробую и отпишусь уже конкретно, работает или нет)

Comment: @Zhenyria *Я просто так понял, что вы возвращаете поля из Truck* Именно так. *А надо сам Truck.* А вот эта фраза с точки зрения SQL не имеет смысла.

Comment: для SQL действительно - не имеет смысла, но тут вопрос про JPQL

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить корректный вывод, если использовать мой изначальный запрос с `DISTINCT`, хотя я не уверен в производительности такого решения.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t FROM Truck t, Dirty d, Gravel g, Sand s
    WHERE t.owner=:owner
    AND ((d.truck.id=t.id AND d.weight=:weight) OR
         (g.truck.id=t.id AND g.weight=:weight) OR
         (s.truck.id=t.id AND s.weight=:weight))
```